# Indexing error in import script

Tags: magento-enterprise, import, indexing, ee-1.12.0.2

I have a module that imports some 10K shops (addresses, details, etc.) from a remote webservice to Magento. At the end of the import, I need to run a specific indexing.

The import part works fine (takes about 1 minute), but the indexing fails about 50% of the time. I was using the following code:

```
$process = Mage::getSingleton('index/indexer')->getProcessByCode('shop_indexer');
$process->reindexEverything();
```

Now I have read about another way to run the indexing. I have removed everything from my module and left only the following code:

```
$process = Mage::getSingleton('index/indexer')->getProcessByCode('shop_indexer');
$process->walk('reindexAll');
```

But this fails every time. <del>I get an error on the frontend:</del>

<del>There has been an error processing your request</del>

**Edit:** the above error was due to another issue in my module. Now I get no error display on the frontend, but still:

I get nothing in the system.log file.

**What would be the correct approach to:**

1. Import data to the Magento database
2. Run a reindex after the import has finished
3. Log the results of the reindexing (log something if it succeeds or fails)

**Edit:** What I don't understand is that reindexing fails when ran from my script, but doing it manually from the backend works fine. What am I missing?

Thanks in advance for any help on that!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So to reindex programatically you can work with the following code.

```
$process = Mage::getModel('index/indexer')->getProcessByCode('process_code');
$process->reindexAll();
```

This will load your indexer process and reindex it.

As to why it errors I do not know but one piece of advice I can give you is to wrap the call inside a try catch block. This way if an exception is thrown you will pick it up and be able to see what the problem is.

Comment: That was a late answer but always welcome. And yes that's what I ended up doing. Thanks!